# SELinux Policy Creation Error regarding Memory and Context Structure

Tags: memory, operating-system, redhat, policy, selinux

I am working on RHEL 7. I have log files of another machine stored here.
I used the following command to create policy :

```
grep -inr "denied" audit.log* | audit2allow -M Policy_File_Name
```

Using this command, I was able to create policy for many of log files. But in some cases I encountered this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/audit2allow", line 365, in <module>
    app.main()
  File "/usr/bin/audit2allow", line 352, in main
    self.__process_input()
  File "/usr/bin/audit2allow", line 180, in __process_input
    self.__avs = self.__parser.to_access()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sepolgen/audit.py", line 591, in to_access
    avc.path = self.__restore_path(avc.name, avc.ino)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sepolgen/audit.py", line 531, in __restore_path
    universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

And for few I encountered this error :

```
libsepol.context_from_record: type celery_t is not defined
libsepol.context_from_record: could not create context structure
libsepol.context_from_string: could not create context structure
libsepol.sepol_context_to_sid: could not convert system_u:system_r:celery_t:s0 to sid
```

Here 'celery_t' changes with respect to target context.

System Condition :

```
[root@selinux-policy-creation abhisheklog]# free -h
           total       used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
 Mem:      31G         261M        27G        8.4M        3.1G         30GB
 Swap:      0B          0B          0B
```

Please provide with Cause and Solution. Thanks.

Comment: You are running a direct python script or some web server here?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am using the mentioned command at the location of audit log files. The logs of another system are stored in my system. There is no role of python or web server here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such error messages mean that there are invalid SE modules present in the file-system, which might be leftovers from previous bad uninstall scripts. Manually deleting these files usually gets one rid of these error messages; but in this case it seems to be the other way around. While there are such orphaned SE modules present, this can cause bogus error messages - therefore I wouldn't even be too sure about the "cannot allocate memory" message. Got the feeling, this might be related to `python2-celery` (where type `celery_t` appears to come from). The problem is that type `celery_t` made it into the audit log, but it is unknown to the machine which runs `audit2allow`.

```
python2-celery-4.2.1-3.el7.noarch : Distributed Task Queue
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/celery
```

The first thing to try might be:

```
sudo yum install python2-celery
```

which might possibly restore the missing type `celery_t`. I mean, if this log file originates from another machine, this machine might have `python2-celery` installed - while the machine which runs the `audit2allow` might simply lack it. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, this was the case. But by now, I made the policies ".te" files manually and compiled them to ".pp". Thanks for the answer